# android modify an xml

Tags: java, android, xml, edit

Is there a way to modify an xml file in android which is located somewhere inside a project. I tried to modify it from assets, res\raw folder, with no success. will it work if I copy the xml file from a project, somewhere outside the app, and use this xml file to edit?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: You should have no problem modifying and xml in or outside the ide (I assume that is what you mean by project), either is fine.

You should specify which ide you are using.

Perhaps you are trying to modify an xml which is not the source, check the path of the document you are modifying.  Improve your question or someone may mark it down.

Comment: What's stopping you from just editing it?  I don't get it.  XML is just text.

Comment: @njzk2 He means instead of `project` say `at runtime`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can copy the xml from your project into a different folder, and then you are able to modify that xml file. The files inside your own project are compiled into the. Apk and thus not modificable.

Answer (score 0):

`will it work if...`: How about trying?
Yes, you will be able to modify it, but it is binary xml... Afterwards you can't just copy it back in, since that would corrupt the .apk file (hashing and so on...), so I don't see how this could help you.